# How to dynamically link button in DotNetNuke 7

Tags: html, dotnetnuke, admin, dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke-settings

I am facing an issue with DNN7 link manager. I have a created a parent site like for example www.dnndemo.com.In home page i created a contact us button(Not included this in main navigation) in home page which will link to contact us page using link manager editor.So the path looks like www.dnndemo.com/contact-us. But if i a create a child site for the same URL i.e www.dnndemo.com/test now when i click on the contact us button which i already created will not redirect to my contact us page. This button still has parent URL link.

Is there any possibility that we can change the URL of the button dynamically based on the parent or child url.Hope i am clear on the issue.Help is much appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create the link as a relative link, rather than as an absolute one.

In your example, make the link "/contact-us" and DNN will take care of the rest.

If you go to Host, HTML Editor Manager you will find a setting to force the editor to generate relative links automatically, so that should help you in the future.  (There are other useful options you might want to adjust there as well/(